# How to pass non-primitive types into Fragment factory method's Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an object with non-primitive attributes that will be initialized with information from an API call:

```
class object(
    val attribute1: String
    val attribute2: Date
)
```

I want to build a Fragment with these attributes as parameters, like so:

```
 private var param1: String? = null
 private var param2: Date? = null
```

The key-value pairs in the Fragment's factory and onCreate methods require primitive types as values

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }


fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            PaymentMethodFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
```

What is the best way to pass this data into a new instance of a fragment?

Comment: Your object can implements parcelable https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable

Comment: This looks good. Thank you.